# xcode validate/submit app has no identities available

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, identity

I'm trying to submit a mac app store and during the testing/submitting step it ask's for an identity.

[image: identity input]

My understanding is that this should be the app store identity, however the only option I have available is Don't sign.

I have verified that my keychain has both my '3rd party developer application' and the 'Apple Worldwide developer relations certificate authority'. Has anyone else ever ran into this problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is both a '3rd party developer application' and a '3rd party installation' certificate. I had only generated the one. Once I did the other, things started working great!